# ST_azimuth creates only NULL values for Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, virtual-layer

I have two layers with points representing two measurements of the same structure using two different methods. The points representing the same structure element have the same ID in both layer.

To compare the results I created a virtual layer calculating the distances between points (which works fine) as well as the direction of the shift.

This is the code I have been using:

```
SELECT
sonar.number AS sonar_id, offset.number AS offset_id,
st_distance(sonar.geometry, offset.geometry) AS distance,
st_azimuth(sonar.geometry, offset.geometry) AS rotation
FROM sonar, offset
WHERE sonar.number = offset.number
```

This creates a layer showing both ID's, a distance (which is correct) as well as a field for rotation. However, this field is `NULL` everywhere. I tried different approaches including converting the result with `degrees()` and entering two random points into `st_azimuth` (e.g. `st_point(1,1), st_point(0,0)`), but the result is always the same.

There must be an error in my syntax, or I totally misunderstand the function `st_azimuth`. Any hints?

Comment: This does work for me `select st_azimuth(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)'),ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'));`. Add `ST_AsEWKT(sonar.geometry),ST_AsEWKT(offset.geometry)` to your SQL (with limit 10) and run it with PSQL so you can see what is really used in ST_Azimuth.

Comment: Does not work for me. I get the error 'No such function: ST_AsEWKT' Could you provide the entire code?

Comment: ST_AsEWKT is a PostGIS function and I suggested you to run it with PSQL. Don't you really have that function? Test for example with `select ST_AsEWKT(ST_AsText('POINT (1 1)'));` What is your PostGIS version?

Comment: I run this in the Virtual Layer Creator in QGIS (see question heading). I don't know how to make sure, it is run explicitly with PostGIS. The PostGIS-Version on my machine is 3.1.1-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, if there is a problem hidden in this approach, but it produced correct results. Instead of using st_-functions, I used the normal functions which are also in the QGIS field calculator. The SQL looks like that:

```
SELECT
sonar.nummer AS sonar_id, offset.nummer AS offset_id, sonar.notiz,
distance(sonar.geometry, offset.geometry) AS distance,
degrees(azimuth(sonar.geometry,offset.geometry)) AS rotation
FROM sonar, offset
WHERE sonar.nummer = offset.nummer
```

Comment: When using Virtual layers, it's not using PostGIS database but a spatialite query on top of existing other data source. You lose all benefits of using PostGIS. If you want a working query using PostGIS, create a database connexion, then, go to "DB Manager" then in the providers, choose PostGIS and double click on your db name connexion. In the menu now, go to "Database" > "SQL Windows". Then, type your query do "Execute" to see an overview of returned result, tick "Load as new layer" then click "Load" and you have a new layer using directly your PostGIS SQL query